# Linear regression in kdb

Tags: regression, kdb

This is how I build linear regression but when I include more than two columns, my code does not work.

```
// Load relevant columns into memory
//
t:?[`data;enlist(=;`date;dat);0b;(ind,dep)!ind,dep];


X:9h$enlist[count[t]#1],t ind;
beta:inv[X mmu flip X] mmu X mmu 9h$t dep;

res:(`yInt,ind)!beta;
```

`ind` is independent fields names in symbols and dep is the dependent fields names in symbol. This part `inv[X mmu flip X]` does not not work. There will be a row that's blank if I include more than two fields for ind and I cannot do `inv`. I am not really sure how I can include more columns/fields for independent variables.

Answer (score 8):

With a minor modification, your code worked for me:

```
  / Generate some random data
  n:10;t:([]x1:n?1f;x2:n?1f;x3:n?1f)
  / Compute y = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 + 4*x3 + small random noise 
  update y:1+(2*x1)+(3*x2)+(4*x3)+n?1e-3 from `t;
  / Define ind and dep
  ind:`x1`x2`x3
  dep:enlist`y
  / Build the design matrix
  X:enlist[count[t]#1f],t ind
  / Compute the regression parameters
  inv[X mmu flip X] mmu X mmu flip t dep
1.00052
1.99973
2.999979
4.000045
```

The only potentially tricky part is to remember to enlist and transpose `dep`.

From your description, it looks like you may have problem with your data.  It either contains NaNs or your `ind` variables are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

I found a google groups question asking about linear regression:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/personal-kdbplus/CRf-kOx-v4I

They mention in this post about using the lsq command:
http://code.kx.com/q/ref/matrixes/#lsq

Another answer give's example code, hopefully this info helps you out.

Comment: thanks, but i have found these answers too. but if it is categorical variable, how do u do linear regression?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a subset of the data you're working with? In general, inv failing would imply to me that you have some nulls in your matrix. This issue can be fixed by using `0f^` before attempting to find the inverse of the matrix. (Fill the null elements of the matrix with float zero.)  
http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#fill
 Quick examples:

```
inv 3 cut 1.1 2.2 3.1 4.5 0n 0n 1.2 7 8f
```

Returns:

```
(0n 0n 0n;0n 0n 0n;0n 0n 0n)
```

Whereas...

```
inv 0f^3 cut 1.1 2.2 3.1 4.5 0n 0n 1.2 7 8f
```

Returns:

```
(0 0.2222222 -0;-1.9512195 0.2753388 0.7560976;1.7073171 -0.2742547 -0.5365854)
```

Comment: Thanks!how are you gonna do this on a partitioned table?

Comment: You can 0f^ the individual columns after you perform your select, or you can use exec on the columns to build the matrix, get the value of the dictionary and then fill the whole thing.